# Cant reach node server running in docker container in vm

Tags: node.js, curl, docker, ip

I have a dockerized node app running inside a container on an ubuntu-vm-host with static address, but can only reach it through localhost. I use  the command:
sudo docker run -d -p 49160:3000 8a5ccd9f4cca
to start the app. I can reach running node servers on the vm without any trouble when they are run in the vm without docker. 
When i curl http://localhost:49160/test i get a response. but if i try to change it to curl http://"correct ip address":49160/test it doesnt work.

The forwarding port shows up when i netstat -l inside the ubuntu-vm-host.
If i do:

```
curl  http://172.17.0.1:49160/test
```

which is the docker0 network interface inet address, it gets through.

[netstat -l command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IanPi.png)

Comment: Why you're using `http://:49160/test`, you should always specify an IP address (or a domain name).

Comment: is this a typo http://:49160/test  ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i wrote http://<correct ip address>:49... and it left out everything inside brackets

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Just connection timeout on client side. No error or signs of request on server side.

Comment: Do you have a firewall on the host, e.g. iptables settings? And can you verify the ip is the host ip, and not the container ip?

Comment: I have tried the ip countless times with node apps running without docker, it's the ip of the host. If it makes anything clearer, it works when i curl the the inet address of the docker0 interface, inside the ubuntu vm.

Comment: is this running in the cloud, if so which ?

Comment: azure, virtual ubuntu machine i have deployed. i have already freed up the incoming and outcoming ports, i have tried the node app on the exact same ports without docker, and it works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the previous irresponsible answer. To debug the issue

**UPDATED**

First to see if the app is running correctly try,

`docker logs <container id>`

if all the console out put that you usually print out is there,

**Scenario 1** : *If it is not*,  run the docker using the -it flag instead of -d manually start the process and check with a curl to debug.

```
docker run -it -p 49160:3000 <image id> /bin/bash
```

**Scenario 2** : *If it is running*, check if the internal ubuntu firewall is enabled using the following, if so if you don't need it disable it.

```
sudo ufw status
```

to disable : `sudo ufw disable`
to allow : `sudo ufw allow 49160`

Comment: It's the other way around. Netstat -l shows the ubuntu-vm listening on port 49160. The node app is listening on port 3000 in it's container.

Comment: ahh did not read the question properly, I will update the answer.

Comment: The app starts running without any issue. 
sudo ufw status gives:
Status: inactive

Comment: can you post the docker inspect of the running docker.